# Haskell generate subsets

Tags: haskell, subset-sum

I have a function 'subsets' which generate all the subsets of a given set:

```
subsets :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
subsets []  = [[]]
subsets (x:xs) = subsets xs ++ map (x:) (subsets xs)
```

How can I combine map, foldl and filter in another function to return me all the subsets with elements that sum up to 0?

**Example: **

```
set    = [1,-1,5,2,-2,3]
result = [[1,-1],[2,-2],[-1,-2,3]]
```

Comment: If only there were some way to filter your list of subsets to return those that summed to 0.

Comment: I tried something like: map (filter((foldl(+) 0)==0)) [[1,-1,0],[0,1]].
I am a little stuck in the syntax(being a beginner)

Comment: `subsetsSum0 = filter ((== 0) . sum) . subsets`

Answer (score 5):

You have subsets already. So we need a function

```
filterSubs :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
filterSubs = --remove all subsets which don't sum to 0
```

So next we'd need a predicate

```
sumZero :: [Int] -> Bool
sumZero xs = sum xs == 0
```

Now, using this and `filter` it's easy to construct `filterSubs`. I'll leave this to you to figure out exactly how that works. And then our solution is trivial

```
zeroSubs = filterSubs . subsets
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you want to take all subsets and then only *keep* the ones that `sum` 0

```
subsetsSum0 ls = filter (\ss -> (sum ss) == 0) (subsets ls)
```

let's make this code point-free

```
subsetsSum0 = filter ((==0) . sum) . subsets
```